# Can't switch to Groovy 2.4 on GGTS

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy, ggts

I followed the following guide to upgrade to grails 3.0 & Groovy 2.4 
But I cannot seem to find where in eclipse (GGTS Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE) I can switch the compiler.

This is the guide I've been following:
https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2015/04/10/grails-3-released-installing-gradle-and-groovy-2-4-support-in-eclipseggts/

Did everything fine until step 5.

Here's the problem:
[image: Can't switch compiler]

All I want is to upgrade my project to Grails 3 & groovy 2.4
Is there any other IDE that supports this perhaps?

Thanks!

Comment: Use Intellij IDE: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/getting-started-with-grails-3.html

Comment: I would love to use Intellij. My company will not spend $500 per exmployee per year...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue...
Just posting this in case someone else gets here.

Apparently the 2.4 compiler did not install correctly as I expected.

The solution was to reinstall Groovy 2.4 Eclipse Feature from this link in eclipse marketplace: http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.4/

[image]

Comment: As of today the release version is available (http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.4/) although pivotal dropped it's support for groovy and grails a while ago.